# How do you make text in a big cell appear at the top instead of the bottom

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}

    \begin{tabular}{|l| 
Formation & \raisebox{0mm}[42mm][1mm] {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Horns_rev_1.png}}
    & {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Horns_rev_2.png}}  &
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{Anholt.png}}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

So because the cell is so big, the text appears in the bottom of the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack: put the text inside a box. As you know the height of your images, you can set the height of the box to this value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
        \makebox(16,40)[c]{Formation} & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{example-image}
    & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{example-image}  &
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=40mm]{example-image}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to stand in the top as well?

Comment: @MathiasAndersen Sure, replace `[c]` by `[t]`

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways. One would  be to use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) which provides the `valign` key-value option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  \hline
  Text & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} \\
  \hline
  Text & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-b} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the `export` option, which allows one to use `adjustbox`'s key-values as part of `\includegraphics`.

You can also raise the content into position manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  \hline
  Text & \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\normalbaselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}} \\
  \hline
  Text & \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\normalbaselineskip` (as opposed to `\baselineskip`) is necessary within a `tabular`, as the default `\baselineskip` is set to `0pt`.

You may ask: "Why move the *images* up/down and not just the *text* (in the first column)?" The reason for this is two-fold:

1. If you move the text upward, you have no idea how high to move it. Unless, of course, you know the height of the image(s). Moving the image is easier as you know it's height while working with it (either a fixed value, or `\height`).
2. What you're interested in is actually changing the vertical anchor point across the row elements. Changing the anchor point of `Text` may still leave you with the image(s) aligned at the bottom.